# material-module.ts file not found after installing material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm very new to Angular and Im trying to install Material design to angular. I tried

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

After the installation I was not able to locate the material-module.ts file in the app root folder.

I tried

```
ng add @angular/material
```

to make sure everything refered correctly. But still that file not present

What I did wrong or I still needs to do something??

Answer (score 0):

> After the installation I was not able to locate the material-module.ts file in the app root folder.

Installed packages/libraries won't be located at app root folder, they are installed in node_modules folders.

After the installation, in order to use one of angular material modules you should import the module you need.

for example, if you want to use material-slider you should import MatSliderModule

```js
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
…
@NgModule ({....
  imports: [...,
  MatSliderModule,
…]
})
```

Now you can use

```js
<mat-slider min="1" max="100" step="1" value="1"></mat-slider>
```

The [Docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#display-a-component) it's a great place to start.